# How to use the actual value of a property in node's code?

Tags: python, nuke

I'm trying to use the value of a variable in code itself and I am not sure how to do it using Python for NUKE. I'm using the following code in a NUKE's node's knob that can't refer to the value of variable name. This knob will be executed later when there will be no variable `name`.

```
name = "aa124"
```

I want to create a one liner code that will be stored in nuke Python knobs and will be executed later.

I can print a string:

```
print("aa124")
```

But I cannot print my property's value:

```
print name
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: ```print name``` - This will print the actual value of variable ```name```. When you are using ```name``` you are referring to the actual value i.e ```aa124```

Comment: If you are only just getting started, ignore Python 2, which is out of support, and concentrate on the currently supported and recommended version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Im using this code in a nuke node knob that cant refer to the value of variable name . because this knob will be executed later when there will be no variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, print any constant value that is not 0 or 1 will preferrably be stored as variables (with capitalized names) in the code module. So, we should not print "aa124" directly but revise the naming of the variable as *NAME* instead of *name*. At the same time, the constant variable *NAME* makes the value more reusable and readable as well.